# ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre "expandible" y "expansible"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Según la RAE, tenemos:

> **[expandible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HHYt1GA)**
>
> 1. adj. Que se puede expandir. *Un material expandible.*
>
> **[expansible](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HHePJTY)**
>
> 1. adj. Fís. Susceptible de expansión.

Dado que *[expansión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HHfIaVu)* es la "acción y efecto de expandir o expandirse", ¿existe alguna sutil diferencia entre ambos términos, o son simplemente intercambiables? Por la definición parece que algo es "expandible" cuando se puede expandir, pero no lo hará si no es necesario, y algo es "expansible" cuando su tendencia natural es a expandirse si nada lo impide. ¿Es eso así? Al consultar el sufijo *-ble* me encuentro con esto:

> **[-ble](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5gagNwr)**
>
> 1. suf. Forma adjetivos casi siempre deverbales. Indica posibilidad pasiva, es decir, capacidad o aptitud para recibir la acción del verbo. [...] Los derivados de verbos intransitivos o de sustantivos suelen tener valor activo.

Es decir, el sufijo indica posibilidad (pasiva o activa), pero que tenga la posibilidad de expandirse no implica que lo vaya a hacer. ¿Luego la única diferencia entre ambas palabras es que "expandible" indica posibilidad pasiva (al provenir de un verbo transitivo) y "expansible" indica posibilidad activa (al provenir de un sustantivo)? ¿Y qué diferencia hay entre ambos tipos de posibilidad, pues?

Comment: Creo que tus conclusiones están yendo un poco lejos. Tanto el _suelen_ como la falta de referencia _explícita_ a verbos transitivos quitan piso a la evidencia de que haya realmente una diferencia entre los verbos. Para mí _expandible_ suena más regular (por lo de _casi siempre deverbales_) y queda más accesible al hablante inculto, mientras que _expansible_ me parece más antiguo (el DRAE incluye derivados como _expansibilidad_, que la versión -dible no tiene). Estoy buscando un poco más de sustento a esto último.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**expandir**

> (Del lat. expandere , extender < pandere , desplegar.)  1 v. tr. y
>   prnl.  Extender, hacer que una cosa ocupe más espacio.    SINÓNIMO:
>   dilatar  2 Hacer que una cosa llegue a más lugares o personas .
>   EJEMPLO: el rumor se expandió rápidamente por toda la ciudad.
>   SINÓNIMO: difundir, propagar

**expansible**

> adj.  FÍSICA  Que se puede expandir o extender.
>
> Fuente: http://www.diccionarios.com/

Serían equivalentes aunque difiere su ámbito para la aplicación. "Expansible" tiene un uso más técnico que "expandible", cuya utilización es más, por decirlo de alguna manera, cotidiana

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta, pero no me queda clara cuál es tu conclusión. ¿Son entonces equivalentes?

Comment: Sí. Me quedó incompleta la respuesta, disculpas.

Serían equivalentes aunque difiere su ámbito para la aplicación. "Expansible" tiene un uso más técnico que "expandible", cuya utilización es más, por decirlo de alguna manera, cotidiana.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la aclaración! ¿Podrías completar la respuesta con esta información? Así quedará más completa y los que vengan después no tendrán que leer los comentarios para enterarse de todo. :-)

Comment: La RAE parece apoyar tu respuesta en [este tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/776035282575618048): "Tienen sentido equivalente. El DLE marca «expansible» como voz técnica de la física." Al final sí que era verdad que estaba yendo un poco lejos con mis divagaciones.